# Multibinding error in the output

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, multibinding

I have a button that is enabled depending on two properties. I used a MultiBinding with a Converter.

**Everything works** but the output keeps saying:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 5 : Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property.; Value='' MultiBindingExpression:target element is 'HGCCommandButton' (Name='btnEliminar'); target property is 'IsEnabled' (type 'Boolean')
```

There are some questions here with similar issues:
[WPF MultiBinding Fails. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447055/wpf-multibinding-fails-why)

Any easy solution or I should make the logic in the ViewModel and bind just to one property?

CODE:
XAML:

```
<utils:HGCCommandButton x:Name="btnEliminar">
                    <utils:HGCCommandButton.IsEnabled>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiValueIsEnabledConverter}"
                                      ConverterParameter="NotEnabledIfIsFromInfoGestionOrIsNew">
                            <Binding Path="IsNew" />
                            <Binding Path="IsAbonado" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </utils:HGCCommandButton.IsEnabled>
                </utils:HGCCommandButton>
```

Converter:

```
public class MultiValueIsEnabledConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (parameter!=null)
            {
                if (values[0] == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue || values[1] == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue) return "";

                var sel = (MultiValueIsEnabledConverterNames)Enum.Parse(typeof(MultiValueIsEnabledConverterNames), parameter.ToString());

                switch (sel)
                {
                   ...

                    case MultiValueIsEnabledConverterNames.NotEnabledIfIsFromInfoGestionOrIsNew:
                        return (bool)NotEnabledIfIsFromInfoGestionOrIsNew(values[0], values[1]);

                    default:
                        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    private static object NotEnabledIfIsFromInfoGestionOrIsNew(object isFromIG, object isNew)
            {
                if ((isFromIG != null) && !(bool)isFromIG)
                {
                    if ((isNew != null) && !(bool)isNew) 
                    {
                        return !((bool)isFromIG && (bool)isNew);
                    }
                    return false;
                }
                return false;
            }
```

ViewModel variables are just two booleans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is quite an odd `ConverterParameter`, is the `StaticResource` you reference for the `Converter` actually an instance of the converter whose code you posted? The error claims that the value is not a bool and that method alone can only return a bool so i doubt that the error is found here.

Can the code in your `Convert` method return anything else but a bool? You need to avoid it if that is possible.

**Edit:** Right here is the problem:

```
if (values[0] == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue || values[1] == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue) return "";
```

You return an empty string which is not compatible with the boolean property,