# Dependency Property to fill list or array

Tags: wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

I have a custom control. This has the ability to do something with several other Controls. I would like it to have an element `NotifyControl` where I can bind some other controls like `NotifyControl="{Binding ElementName=controlA}"`. This is fine but I would like to write down `n` controls. So maybe a list in the element value or noting the element multiple times. Like

```
<MyControl NotifyControl="{Binding ElementName=a}" NotifiyControl="{Binding ElementName=b}" />
```

or

```
<MyControl NotifyControl="{Binding ElementName=a}, {Binding ElementName=b}" />
```

Which one is possible and how do to it? I got no luck with an array type, maybe my notation like above is wrong.

---

**EDIT**:

I now have

```
<MyControl>
    <MyControl.NotifyControls>
        <NotifyControlWrapper View="{Binding ElementName=details}" Test="entry one" />
        <NotifyControlWrapper View="{Binding ElementName=gauge}" Test="e2" />
    </MyControl.NotifyControls>
</MyControl>
<OtherControl x:Name="details" />
```

`NotifyControls` is a DependencyProperty and filled with two entries, so this part works fine. The source of `NotifyControlWrapper` is just a class derived from `DependencyObject` with the two dependency properties `View` (type `INotifyControl`) and `Test` (type `String`).

As I sayed my list gets two entries with two `NotifyControlWrapper`. But while `Test` contains the given String, `View` is `null`. Why is that or how to debug?

Comment: its not really clear what you are trying to do but it sounds to me like ObservableCollection should be involved?

Comment: Its not like that because there are no changes at runtime. But I reuse the control in different windows and every time it should highlight one or more other controls. It works fine with `NotifyControl1="{Binding ElementName=a}" NotifyControl2="{Binding ElementName=b}"` but thats not like any good programming.

Answer (score 2):

Neither one in your question is possible.  You can't add the same property twice so #1 won't work.  You can't add two bindings so #2 won't work.  I would add a property NotifyControls as a List type.  NotifyControl could still be available as a separate item or to add to the list of controls in NotifyControls.  You can add items in Xaml:

```
<MyControl.NotifyControls>
    <ControlWrapper Control="{Binding ElementName=a}"/>
    <ControlWrapper Control="{Binding ElementName=b}"/>
</MyControl.NotifyControls>
```

ControlWrapper would just have a single member property, Control, so that you can specify the binding.

Comment: So `NotifyControls` is a `List<ControlWrapper>` and `ControlWrapper` is a class which inherits from `DependencyObject`?

Comment: I would use List<ControlWrapper>, yes, but ControlWrapper does not have to inherit from DependencyObject (or anything).  It can be just class ControlWrapper { Control Control { get; set; } }

Comment: This looks good. But I have ControlWrapper to inherit DependencyObject otherwise Control cannot be a DependencyProperty. But no problem with that.

The problem is, Control-property is not set. When accessing the list I get the correct ammount of ControlWrapper entries and if I add a string property `Test` its content is correct. But `Control` is always empty. Must be binding be specified in any special way in this case?

Comment: Did you made ControlWrapper a DependencyObject and Control a DependencyProperty, or did you use one way binding instead? Are you getting any binding errors in the output window in the debugger?

Comment: Yes, DependencyObject and DependencyProperty. And you are right, there is a biinding error in the output window. Did not know that this can happen without an exception!

Comment: It says
`System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:(no path); DataItem=null; target element is 'NotifyCustomerViewWrapper' (HashCode=23337915); target property is 'View' (type 'ICustomerView')` (you see I am using an interface and some different names)

Comment: You can't automatically bind an element to an interface.  Change View to be a UIElement, or use a value converter to convert to ICustomerView.

Comment: The interface cannot be the problem. When I use `NotifyControl1="{Binding ElementName=details}"` it can be binded properly. Also it does not work when switching to `UIElement`.

Comment: OK, try explicitly setting the DataContext in the code behind as in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447055/wpf-multibinding-fails-why or this answer http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/aff23943-5483-40b2-816b-4ce687bc6bf8/

Answer (score 0):

If N is fixed, you can use a MultiBinding (with a converter):

```
<MyControl>
    <MyControl.NotifyControl>
        <MultiBinding Converter="...">
            <Binding ElementName="controlA" />
            <Binding ElementName="controlB" />
            <Binding ElementName="controlC" />
            <Binding ElementName="controlD" />
            <Binding ElementName="controlE" />
            ...
        </MultiBinding>
    </MyControl.NotifyControl>
</MyControl>
```

If N changes, an option would be to add an ObservableCollection<> to your class which you add/remove the controls to, and then bind to it (again, with a converter)

```
<MyControl NotifyControl="{Binding ElementName=ParentElement, Path=MyObservableCollection, Converter=...}" />
```